# All combinations of elements of two lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, combinations

Given two lists, `[a, b]` and `[c, d]`, I'd like to get the following result:

```hs
[(a,c), (a,d), (b,c), (b,d)]
```

How can I do this in Haskell? Is there a built-in function for this, or should I implement one myself?

Comment: When types of `[a, b]` and `[c, d]` are equal, you can write `sequence [[a, b], [c, d]]`.

Answer (score 35):

```
[ (x,y) | x<-[a,b], y<-[c,d] ]
```

This doesn't really require any further explanation, does it?

Comment: No, it doesn't indeed, thanks; I was just wondering whether there was a builtin that does this; something like `combos xs ys` that produces the same result.

Comment: @Ben: `combos = liftA2(,)`, which is basically equivalent to Jubobs' suggestion.

Comment: @leftaroundabout very nice use of applicatives!

Answer (score 23):

Applicative style all the way!

```hs
λ> :m + Control.Applicative
λ> (,) <$> ['a','b'] <*> ['c','d']
[('a','c'),('a','d'),('b','c'),('b','d')]
```

(I've eschewed any `String` syntactic sugar above, in order to stay close to your example.)

For information, `(,)` is special syntax for a function that takes two arguments and makes a pair out of them:

```
λ> :t (,)
(,) :: a -> b -> (a, b)
```

---

Edit: As noted by [leftaroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745903/leftaroundabout) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093912/all-combinations-of-elements-of-two-lists-in-haskell#comment52082958_32093988), you can also use `liftA2`:

```hs
λ> :m + Control.Applicative
λ> let combine = liftA2 (,)
λ> combine "ab" "cd"
[('a','c'),('a','d'),('b','c'),('b','d')]
```

Answer (score 12):

How can you do this in an imperative pseudocode?

```
for each element x in [a,b]:
    for each element y in [c,d]:
        produce (x,y)
```

In Haskell, this is written as

```
outerProduct xs ys =
   do
       x <- xs          -- for each x drawn from xs:
       y <- ys          --   for each y drawn from ys:
       return (x,y)     --      produce the (x,y) pair
```

---

*(following comments by leftaroundabout)* this is of course *extremely* close to how [`liftM2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM2) monadic combinator is defined, so in fact

```
outerProduct = liftM2 (,)
```

which  is the same as `liftA2 (,)`, and its various re-writes in terms of list comprehensions, `concatMap` function, `>>=`, `<$>` and `<*>` operators.

Conceptually though this is the stuff of the `Applicative` – which would be better named as `Pairing`, – because this pairing up of the elements of two *"containers" ⁄ "carriers" ⁄ whatever* is exactly what Applicative Functor is about. It just so happens that Haskell's `do` notation works for monads, and not (*yet*) [for applicatives](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ApplicativeDo).

In some sense *compile-time* nested loops *are* Applicative ⁄ Pairing functors; Monads add the ability to create nested loops on the fly, depending on the values produced by an "outer" enumeration.

Comment: Worth to note that `do`-notation and list comprehensions are actually both syntactic sugar for the the same monadic combinators, namely `[a,b] >>= \x -> [c,d] >>= \y -> return (x,y)`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, that's simply not true. List comprehensions have not one but two treatments in the desugarer, neither of which produces `>>=` or `return`.

Comment: Indeed; one needs to enable `-XMonadComprehensions` so the list comprehensions actually use `>>=` and `return`. Without that extension, they use the equivalent list-specific functions.

Answer (score 10):

The most inuitive would be using list comprehension, other aproaches include using applicative functors:

```
(,) <$> [1,2,3] <*> [4,5,6]
```

So what does this do?

Remember that `(,) :: a -> b -> (a, b)` Takes two arguments and returns a tuple.

`<$>` is acutally fmap, `(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`
It takes a function and lift it. In this case it takes `(,)` and lift it to work on list. So `let x = (,) <$> [1,2]` would generate `x :: [b -> (Integer, b)]` which is the the list of functions that takes `b` and returns tuple with one fixed argument (Integer,b). Finally we apply it using `<*>` to generate all the combinations.

Answer (score 8):

use List Comprehension:

```
s = [a,b]
s' = [c,d]

all_combinations = [(x,y) | x <- s, y <- s']
```