# All-to-all pairings of two lists in Haskell without list comprehension

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I am reading through Bird and Wadler's nice book in Functional programming
and trying to solve the exercises in Haskell.

The chapter on  Lists has a section which says that any list comprehension 
can be implemented in terms of `map`, `filter` and `concat` and subsidiary functions which one might need for `map`

I am having trouble implementing the following expression in terms of these building blocks.

```
[(x,y) | x<- xs, y<- ys]
```

How would one use map and filter for this?

I got as far as doing

`concat [ map (\ a -> (a,x)) ys | x<-xs ]`

I suspect we have to use currying cleverly here, but i can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing syntactic sugar: List comprehension in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029046/removing-syntactic-sugar-list-comprehension-in-haskell)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093912/all-combinations-of-elements-of-two-lists-in-haskell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well for each `x` you need all `y`s so:

```
\x -> map (\y -> (x,y)) ys
```

now you only need to map this over all `xs`

```
cross xs ys = map (\x -> map (\y -> (x,y)) ys) xs
```

example:

```
> cross [1..3] "AB"
[[(1,'A'),(1,'B')],[(2,'A'),(2,'B')],[(3,'A'),(3,'B')]]
```

Comment: Very nice! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not sure if ApplicativeDo is allowed as part of your "building blocks", but if it is, this can easily be implemented by mapping the tuple function over the first list, and applying that list to the second.

```
import Control.Applicative

let xs = [1,2,3]
    ys = [4,5,6]

(,) <$> xs <*> ys
```

Result:

```
[(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6)]
```