# Need explanation for basic do block syntax

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension, monads, do-notation

In ghci, I wrote:

```
 let x = do
    i <- [1..5]
    j <- [2..4]
    return i
```

Expected result:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Actual result:

```
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5]
```

I don't understand the logic behind that output. I think the reason might be something about monad, but I am very new to functional programming, I wish someone could explain it a little bit.

I've also tried the equavalent form in List-comprehension and the result is the same, which means there is something basic I misunderstood here.

Comment: If you're familiar with programming in an imperative language, this is comparable to a nested for loop. Otherwise you can look up how to desugar do syntax, work through the defns etc.

Comment: try `[ (i,0) | i <- [1..5], j <- [2..4]]`, `[ (i,j) | i <- [1..5], j <- [2..4]]`.

Comment: The syntax is easy. Your problem is that you don't understand how the list monad works.

Comment: on that note, [Haskell Monad - How does Monad on list work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172904/haskell-monad-how-does-monad-on-list-work).

Comment: related: [All combinations of elements of two lists in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093912/all-combinations-of-elements-of-two-lists-in-haskell).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've also tried the equavalent form in List-comprehension and the result is the same

Good idea. It so happens that for lists, `do` notation does exactly the same as list comprehensions. (In fact, there's [a syntactic extension](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/monad-comprehensions) that allows you to use list-comprehension notation for any monad, like you can use `do` notation for any monad.)

So, you're asking why `[a | a<-[0,1], b<-[2,3]]` gives `[0,0,1,1]` instead of `[0,1]`. The way this looks surprising is if you think about list comprehensions as *set comprehensions* like you'd find in maths. But lists aren't sets, though Haskellers do often use lists as a makeshift stand-in for sets. If lists comprehensions acted as set comprehension, then

```
  [x | x <- [0,1,0]]
```

should also yield only `[0,1]` as its result (or at least, it should yield *the same* result as `[x|x<-[0,1]]` does).

In general this sort of weeding-out-duplicates requires equality checks, and if you want to make it efficient also either an ordering or a hashing method. Lists don't do any such thing, so if you want set-like behaviour you should use a set-implementing data structure. [`Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.3.1/docs/Data-Set.html#t:Set) and [`HashSet`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.12.0/docs/Data-HashSet.html#t:HashSet) are the most common.

Answer (score 6):

This is because the do mechanism does not care (fortunately) about whether or not the innermost code actually refers to (some of) the loop variables.

See you always get 3*5=15 values regardless of innermost code:

```
 λ> 
 λ> xs1 = do { i <- [1..5] ; j <- [2..4] ; return i }
 λ> xs1
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5]
 λ> 
 λ> xs2 = do { i <- [1..5] ; j <- [2..4] ; return 9 }
 λ> xs2
[9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]
 λ> 
 λ> xs3 = do { i <- [1..5] ; j <- [2..4] ; return (i,j) }
 λ> xs3
[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4),(5,2),(5,3),(5,4)]
 λ> 
 λ> length xs1
15
 λ> length xs2
15
 λ> length xs3
15
 λ>
```

As far as I can tell, this is perfectly standard behavior, that Haskell shares with C, C++, Fortran, Python ...

A C++ equivalent example:

```
#include  <vector>
#include  <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int>  vi{1,2,3,4,5};
    std::vector<int>  vj{2,3,4};

    for (int i: vi)
        for (int j: vj)
            std::cout << i << ", ";

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

C++ output:

```
$ ./a.out
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
$
```

Comment: (I know "depends on" is the accepted jargon but it can actually be unclear what that means. using "refers to" instead could be clearer; also using `xs1 = do { i <- [1..5] ; j <- [2..4] ; return (i,0) }` and `xs1 = do { i <- [1..5] ; j <- [2..4] ; return (i,j) }` as the additional examples.)

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explaination!

Comment: @WillNess - Points taken, thanks. However I still prefer to keep the first example as is, because this is _verbatim_ from the OP's question text.

Comment: yes, hence "additional". (I think (i,0) shows the structure of it better than just some random value.)